# C# application freezes

Tags: c#

after pressing on the execute bottom the ssh command is sent and executed perfectly but after it, the app freezes and I cant press on any other button. This is the code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SshClient cSSH = new SshClient("ip", 22, "root", "pass");
        cSSH.Connect();
        SshCommand x = cSSH.RunCommand("ssh command");
        cSSH.Disconnect();
        cSSH.Dispose();                      
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error:" + error);
    }
}
```

**edit:**

The code stuck on following line:

```
SshClient cSSH = new SshClient("ip", 22, "root", "pass");
```

Comment: What is the exact line where it freezes?

Comment: It's because your code runs in one thread with UI. Create another thread and run code here.

Comment: Side note: do not put `Dispose()` explicitly, use "using" instead: `using (SshClient cSSH = new ...) {...}`

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230255/ssh-net-library-sshclient-dispose-public-connection
It's the same problem.

Comment: You're using your actual IP where you have the string `"ip"`, right?

Comment: Are you sure it's not freezing on the connect statement? It might timeout and give you an exception if you wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *Task* for this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        using (SshClient cSSH = new SshClient("ip", 22, "root", "pass")
        {
            cSSH.Connect();
            SshCommand x = cSSH.RunCommand("ssh command");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This method will return before the task has completed. There is no sense in wrapping it in a try...catch block, because if anything goes wrong, you're not going to hear about it. You'd have to await the task in order for exceptions to bubble up, in which case you're back to square one.

Comment: ``StartNew`` starts a thread asynchronously, so ``try``, ``catch`` has no effect

Comment: @Asad that's exactly what we want.

Comment: @greenhoorn It doesn't seem like that's what OP wants, since they want to show an error if something goes wrong with the attempt.

Comment: +1 Up for elegance. How about an external bool flag to check if the previous *RunCommand* has finished its job before creating a new SshClient ? Just a thought.

Comment: @Asad You can't have both. Either you wait until the execution completes (UI freezes) or you do it async and let the user do some stuff (you can still show him a message if the completion fails)

Comment: @greenhoorn You can have both. You just need to return the task from the method so the OP can await it elsewhere and update the UI to show errors once the task completes.

Comment: @Asad Ups, my comment disagrees itself. You're right, that's what I meant the second part :-)