# C# SSH command execute

Tags: c#, button, ssh, console, freeze

i need a small help with my app. When I press the button the app freezes until ssh complete the commnand which was sent. I tried solution from [C# application freezes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117915/c-sharp-application-freezes) but when I tried to use  `Task.Factory.StartNew(()...`  i dont have a output in console. There is my code:

```
var cmd = SSH.CreateCommand("apt update && apt upgrade -y");
                    var asynch = cmd.BeginExecute();
                    var reader = new StreamReader(cmd.OutputStream);

                    while (!asynch.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                            continue;
                        Console.Write(result);
                    }
                    cmd.EndExecute(asynch);
```

Does anyone have anything to do with it?

Comment: Is this a WPF app?

Comment: @VarChar42 no Its WFA, Windows Forms

Answer (score 0):

You are probably blocking your GUI thread with your while loop.

You need to run your code async.

```cs
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Task sshTask = RunCommand();
}


public static async Task RunCommand()
{
    var cmd = SSH.CreateCommand("apt update && apt upgrade -y");
    var asynch = cmd.BeginExecute();
    var reader = new StreamReader(cmd.OutputStream);

    while (!asynch.IsCompleted)
    {
        var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            continue;
        Console.Write(result);
    }
    cmd.EndExecute(asynch);
}
```